# ValueError at /assignment/get/ Field 'zip' expected a number but got 'zip'

Tags: django

While storing data from `csv` file to database I am getting error:

```
ValueError at /assignment/get/
  Field 'zip' expected a number but got 'zip'
```

model.py

```
from django.db import model

class csvData(models.Model):
   zip=models.IntegerField()
   lat=models.IntegerField()
   lng=models.IntegerField()
```

views.py

```
import csv
from .models import csvData

def get(request):
    fname="uszips.csv"
    with open(fname) as csvfile:
       csv_reader=csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
       for row in csv_reader:
           csvdata=csvData()
           csvdata.zip=row[0]
           csvdata.lat=row[1]
           csvdata.lng=row[2]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First row is probably the header, so the names of the columns.
Try skipping the first row.

Also, you need to convert the values to integers, because they all will be strings.

Maybe like this:

```
def get(request):
    ...
    with open(fname) as csvfile:
       csv_reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')

       for i, row in enumerate(csv_reader):
           if i == 0:
               # skip first row
               continue

           csvdata = csvData()
           csvdata.zip = int(row[0])
           csvdata.lat = int(row[1])
           csvdata.lng = int(row[2])
   ...
```

Comment: I want to print only zip column using restapi @api_view(['GET'])        
def zipcodes(request):
    tasks= csvData.objects.values_list('zip')
    serializer = TaskSerializer(tasks, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)